# I have been able to write a code that print out the arithmetic progression but i need assitance on how to print it in 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, int

I was asked to write a code the print out the arithmetic dimension in 2 dimensional array. I have already wrote the code to print the arithmetic progression but i don't have idea on how to print it in 2 dimensional array. Here is my code any help would be appreciated

```
package task3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArithmeticProgression {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double firstTerm = 0;
    double numberOfTerms = 0;
    double nthTerm = 0;
    double commonDifference = 0;
    double  sum= 0;
    double term = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter the value of a (First Term) : "); 
    firstTerm = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the value of d (Common Difference) : "); 
    commonDifference = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the value of n (Number of terms) : "); 
    numberOfTerms = input.nextDouble();

    nthTerm = firstTerm + (numberOfTerms - 1) * commonDifference;

    sum = numberOfTerms * (2 * firstTerm + (numberOfTerms - 1) * commonDifference)/2;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The Arithmetic Progression is as follows :");

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++){
        term = firstTerm + i * commonDifference;
        System.out.print(term+" + ");
    }

    System.out.println("...");
    System.out.println("The nthTerm of the series : " + nthTerm);
    System.out.println("The Sum of n terms of series : " + sum);
}
    }
```

Comment: This lends itself better to a 1D array. How are the 2D rows & columns meant to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specifying a relationship between the rows & columns in a 2D array, this progression lends itself better to a 1D array. In that case you could use:

```
double[] terms = new double[(int)numberOfTerms];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++) {
   terms[i] = firstTerm + i * commonDifference;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(terms));
```